# LC3 Assembly code loop not null terminating?

Tags: assembly, lc3

I am currently trying to get my assembly lc3 program of Getstring to work which gets a string using the getletter subroutine and then is supposed to terminate/exit the subroutine once a enter/newline is pressed. But when I simulate it, the code gets to the RET and just goes back to the ADD R1, R0, #-10 line instead of exiting to main. How would I terminate the loop or get it to return to main?

[GetString code: program that isn't functioning right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jOK3J.png)

[GetLetter subroutine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTPkt.png)

UPDATED CODE:
GETSTRING
;Save ALL registers that you change except for return Registers.
ST R1, GS_R1    ;Save R1 as an example.
ST R7, GS_R7

```
;.... PUT YOUR CODE HERE ....
```

ADD R1, R0, #0

GS_TOP

JSR GETLETTER

ADD R1, R0, #-10

BRZ GS_DONE

STR R0, R1, #0

ADD R1, R1, #1

BRNZP GS_TOP

GS_DONE
ST R1, #0

```
;Registers registers you used.
LD R1, GS_R1    ;Restore R1
LD R7, GS_R7
RET ;This subroutine should ONLY have one return here.
```

;Storage for GETSTRING.
;All .fill, .stringz, .blkw labels used in this subroutine should go here.
GS_R1   .fill 0     ;Storage location for R1 in GETSTRING
GS_R7   .fill 0
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------
;END OF GETSTRING
;------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Here is my error:
The following hint(s) may help you locate some ways in which your solution may be improved:

Character wrong in string at position 1: ' ' should be 'H'. (2 occurrences)

Character wrong in string at position 2: ' ' should be 'H'.

Character wrong in string at position 1: ' ' should be '�'.

Character wrong in string at position 3: ' ' should be '�'.

Character wrong in string at position 2: ' ' should be 'V'.

Character wrong in string at position 2: ' ' should be 'S'.

Character wrong in string at position 2: ' ' should be 'n'.

Character wrong in string at position 1: ' ' should be 'b'.

Comment: Please don't post code as images.

Answer (score 0):

When one function either calls another function or invokes a trap, it must save its incoming return address parameter, which is in R7, because this register will get repurposed for those operations.

For example, when A calls B, it passes B a return address in R7.  B is supposed to use that return address provided by A to return to the proper call site and resume A.  However, if B calls C, then it also provides a return address in R7, which C is supposed to use to return to B.  So, if B fails to preserve the incoming return address from A, then it's own work to call C will destroy that value and its linkage back to A is lost.

Comment: So how would I fix that? Do i need to save and restore R7 in GetString?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: I tried saving and restoring GL_R7 in Getstring and that didn't work. I think I'm supposed to be storing 0/nul to end the loop but not sure if thats the problem or not

Comment: You may have more than one problem.  The control flow problem -- RET going to the wrong place -- is due to wiping out R7.  Here's how to debug it: on entry to the first function, observe the R7 value.  When you reach the RET of that first function, verify the value in R7.  If it is the same as upon that function's entry, then it will return to where it was called from.  If not, then find out why not.

Comment: Ok I was able to figure out the loop not halting/exiting. That part is fixed. Now i seem to be having a problem with letters/characters not being written or saved to memory? I updated the original question  with my current code and the error.